# How to cast a Dask Series as string type if it contains an unhashable type?

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I would like to call `.value_counts()` on an arbitrary Dask Series, and I want to cast the Series as type *string* if it contains an unhashable type. I don't want to cast the series to a string if I don't have to. I also don't want to call `.compute()` before calling `.value_counts()`. I have tried

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[[1], ["foo"], ["foo", "bar"]]})
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
srs = df["a"]

try:
    val_counts = srs.value_counts()
except TypeError:
    srs = srs.astype(str)
    val_counts = srs.value_counts()

val_counts.compute()
```

which gives the error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

And

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[[1], ["foo"], ["foo", "bar"]]})
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
srs = df["a"]

def func(srs):
    try:
        val_counts = srs.value_counts()
    except TypeError:
        srs = srs.astype(str)
        val_counts = srs.value_counts()
    return val_counts

val_counts = dask.compute(func(srs))
```

which gives the same error.

I have also tried

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[[1], ["foo"], ["foo", "bar"]]})
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
srs = df["a"]

if srs.apply(lambda y: isinstance(y, list), meta=srs).any():
    srs = srs.astype(str)

srs.value_counts().compute()
```

which gives the error

> TypeError: Trying to convert dd.Scalar<series-..., type=str> to a boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe convert lists into something hashable like a tuple first?

```
s.apply(tuple).value_counts()  ?
```